# Best way to reload daemon state - from saved data in my custom format or a persistent database?

Tags: python, database, daemon, persistent-object-store

I have a infinite process running and end of each day it basically writes to a file and populates internal objects with the updated data.

It's running on Ubuntu and written in Python.

Kindly advice what would be the best approach to restore the data if the process crashes/restarted etc.

Should I read all the files generated so far and update the newly created object so that it has all backed up information available, or should the data kept in a DB kind of thing ?

Comment: Please indicate the following in your post: Operation System, Language, Type of data access code (binary/xml/database).  Indicate why you need to restore the data - instead of simply starting afresh.  Then say what you have tried and why it didn't work or you didn't like it.

Comment: Both of your suggestions seem like fine choices, but without more information we can't really help.  In any case any answer to your question as stated must be a matter of opinion - which is frowned upon in questions on stackoverflow since it just ends up in a fight between people who like databases, or don't like them.  Please give some criteria on which to select an answer - e.g. easy of programming, speed of reload.  You might like to indicate the size and complexity (and even structure) of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the update.The OS is going to be ubuntu and programming language is Python.The daily data is going to be populated in python objects.So for each updates we are going to do object lookup and update. In case of process crash as the obj is lost we might try to file read/DB lookup and update the newly object.

Comment: Can't you "dump" the state of the related objects as Python pickles to the filesystem and then provide some recovery mechanism for re-reading the pickles in case of a crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) module is ideal for state - it gives a nicer api and a little more than a straight pickle - ideal for when a (traditional) database seems like overkill.

Comment: Which one is faster cPickle or Shelve and easy to maintain?

Comment: I would punt shelve as its Pickle api os abstracted away.